# Encriptar y Desencriptar ID obtenido por parámetro GET en php

Tags: php, md5

Tengo un problema, espero alguien de la comunidad me pueda orientar a resolverlo. Verán, estoy mostrando información de un usuario, el cual obtengo el ID por parámetro GET. La idea es "encriptar" ese ID para mostrar el HASH en la URL por **ejemplo**:
 sisitema.com/?clienteid=SDAS9238J2 
En vez de sisitema.com/?clienteid=1

Estoy haciendo uso de este código para encriptar y desencriptar el ID y en teoría todo funciona "bien":
https://gist.github.com/neomadara/b1e0068d1a1a7cb859d5

**El problema**:
Al momento de encriptar, en algunas ocasiones me genera cadenas de este tipo (con signos de +), y al obtenerlas por GET y desencriptarlas me marca errores :( porque entiendo que cuando el caracter + aparece en una URL representa un espacio vacío, entonces aquí se muere el sistema.

> vpmn6Sbom5wbolZmX7qKtR4DdBTdhT+DiVkh4atMIKg=

Necesito saber como exluir ese carcter para que las cadenas que se generen puedan ser leídas correctamente o bien, saber como leerlas correctamente para poder hacer las consultas a la BD.

Gracias.

Comment: Por que no lo manda por post(?)

Comment: Necesito mandarlo por GET para generar una URL del cliente, pero que proteja los ID de la base de datos.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta para incluir el código completo con el que estás trabajando.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya ha quedado resuelto :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando generas la URL debes codificar el hash con `urlencode()`. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php $hash = "vpmn6Sbom5wbolZmX7qKtR4DdBTdhT+DiVkh4atMIKg="; ?>
<a href="/?clienteid=<?= urlencode($hash) =?>">Usuario</a>
```

Con esto, en la URL el `+` será reemplazado por `%2B`, lo que genera este html que "no confunde" el "+" con espacios:

```
<a href="/?clienteid=vpmn6Sbom5wbolZmX7qKtR4DdBTdhT%2BDiVkh4atMIKg%3D">Usuario</a>
```

Aquí, en teoría deberías recoger el parámetro usando `GET['clienteid']` y aplicarle `urldecode()` para decodificar los caracteres `%xx`. Sin embargo, en el [manual de PHP:urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.urldecode.php) dice:

> **Advertencia** Las superglobales `$_GET` y `$_REQUEST` ya están decodificadas. El uso de `urldecode()` en un elemento en `$_GET` o `$_REQUEST` puede tener resultados inesperados y peligrosos.

Por lo que deberías probar si `GET['clienteid']` **ya está** decodificado. Si no lo está, accede al parámetro usando `urldecode()`:

```
$hash = urldecode($_GET['clienteid']);
```

Comment: Agradezco infinitamente tu respuesta sin embargo no me funciona. :/  https://s30.postimg.org/qah32qj9d/captura.png

Comment: El manual de php indica que las variables $_GET ya vienen decodificadas. Modifiqué mi respuesta incluyendo este dato.

Comment: Lo he probado como me lo planteas, ha quedado solucionado. GRACIAS INFINITAS!.