# encriptar / desencriptar como estructura MD5 (resultado encriptado solo numeros y letras) con php

Tags: php, md5

primero que nada, gracias anticipada por leer este hilo.

Verán, yo utilizo las siguientes funciones para encriptar/desencriptar algunas variables a nivel de servidor y crear URLs.
Ya uso esta función:
https://gist.github.com/neomadara/b1e0068d1a1a7cb859d5
Incluso ya me ayudaron aqui mismo con unas dudas que tenía (acá el enlace):
[Encriptar y Desencriptar ID obtenido por parámetro GET en php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65706/encriptar-y-desencriptar-id-obtenido-por-par%C3%A1metro-get-en-php)

El problema es el siguiente:
Estoy elminando contenido con ajax, y para ello a cada contenedor en HTMl le pongo un identificador único encriptado. El problema es que por ejemplo: si el ID del registro es 1 la estructura que me arroja las funciones anteriores es algo así:

> t+i+6lJ95/fVPYL9+wPkaKc8RGheD/lbkx7chHT/zl4=

Es decir, el resultado enriptado tiene los caracteres "/","+","=". Entonces, al tratar de manipular esos identificadores desde jquery me arroja estos errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces se me ocurre, encriptar mis identificadores al estilo MD5. Es decir, puros números y letras, así:

> c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b

Sin embargo, tengo sabido de antemano que MD5 no se puede desencriptar, por lo tanto me gustaría que me ayudaran a orientarme como (utilizando la función que actualmente tengo o creando una nueva), puedo encriptar mis IDs pero que como resultado solo tenga números y letras, así:

> c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b

Muchas gracias por su orientación. Saludos

PD: Es importante descriptar el resultado para obtener el identificador y poder hacer el delete a la base de datos.

Comment: En mi caso cuando utilice eso, solo me retornaba '/' y lo solvente realizando un replace `str_replace('/', '-', $this->encriptar($concatenar));` así sustituía los '/' por '-'; antes de desencriptar, volvía a hacer el replace inverso.. quizás tu `$key` es la que este generando los caracteres `+ e =` de sobra prueba con otra $key..

Comment: Mi recomendación es que dejes de utilizar esas funciones, están basadas en el uso de `mcrypt_encrypt` y `mcrypt_decrypt` ambas declaradas obsoletas y su uso está totalmente desaconsejado.

Comment: ¿Que funciones me recomiendas @Xerif?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las funciones `mcrypt_encrypt` y `mcrypt_decrypt` han sido declaradas obsoletas y su uso está totalmente desaconsejado (véase la documentación [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) y [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php)) en su lugar se recomienda utilizar la librería [OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/es/book.openssl.php) en su ultima versión.

Te expongo un ejemplo comentado para hacer lo que buscas, simplemente adaptalo a tus necesidades.

```
<?php

/**
 * Función para encriptar
 */
function my_encrypt($data, $key) {
    // Generamos una cadena de bytes pseudo-aleatoria en base al método de cifrado
    // en este caso: blowfish
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('blowfish'));
    // Ciframos los datos usando blowfish
    $cifrado = openssl_encrypt($data, 'blowfish', $key, 0, $iv);
    // Añadimos el $iv y retornamos en base64
    // el $iv es necesario para poder decodificar los datos por eso lo unimos a 
    // los datos mediante un separador único (|||)
    return base64_encode($cifrado . '|||' . $iv);
}

/**
 * Función para desencriptar
 */
function my_decrypt($data, $key) {
    // Decodificamos los datos y dividimos por el separador único (|||)
    $dataIv = explode('|||', base64_decode($data), 2);
    // comprobamos que tenemos 2 valores
    if(count($dataIv) != 2) {
        return false;
    }
    // Asignamos los datos, para una mejor lectura del código
    $data = $dataIv[0];
    $iv =  $dataIv[1];
    // Validamos longitud correcta del IV
    if(strlen($iv) != openssl_cipher_iv_length('blowfish')) {
        return false;
    }
    // desciframos los datos y retornamos
    return openssl_decrypt($data, 'blowfish', $key, 0, $iv);
}

// Nuestra clave de cifrado
$key = 'Esto es un ejemplo de contraseña';
// Datos a cifrar
$texto = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ';

echo "Clave de cifrado: <br>";
echo $key."<br><br>";

echo "Texto original: <br>";
echo $texto."<br><br>";

echo "Cifrado: <br>";
$texto_cifrado = my_encrypt($texto, $key);
echo $texto_cifrado . "<br><br>";

echo "Descifrado: <br>";
echo my_decrypt($texto_cifrado, $key);
```

Si necesitas saber los tipos de cifrado disponibles en tu sistema puedes utilizar el siguiente código:

```
$cifrados         = openssl_get_cipher_methods();
$cifrados_y_alias = openssl_get_cipher_methods(true);
$alias_cifrados   = array_diff($cifrados_y_alias, $cifrados);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($cifrados);
print_r($alias_cifrados);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, eso es lo que necesitaba saber!!  Muy amable! me pongo a trabajar.

Comment: Hola Xerif grcias por tu respuesta, verás, estoy utilizando tu código en mi proyecto (gracias infinitas), pero tengo un problema, te cuento. Estoy encriptando los ID con esa función para obtener algo más seguro, y hasta el momento todo bien, hago base64_encode y decode, pero el problema viene cuando la URL es modificada, como los valores de entrada son mayores la función muere. Hay manera de cacacharlo? http://prntscr.com/jr08jb Gracias de antemano.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jr09h9

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta en algun punto estas alterando el `IV` pues te esta diciendo que le estas pasando un byte de mas. Por eso en el cifrado utilizamos `openssl_cipher_iv_length`, para determinar el numero de byte del vector del algoritmo de cifrado.

Comment: Efectivamente, lo que pasa esque estoy trayendo URLs con los Identificadores encriptados. Tipo: candidato&id=VVdSd2VFeHdhVGhMZ, pero entonces necesito validar que la URL (o por lo menos el identificador encriptado) no sea manipulado, para mostrar mensajes, hacer redirecciones, etc, sin embargo, estoy en ese dilema, el por alguna razón un usuario modificar ese identificador encriptado me sale ese error, por eso es lo que te pregunto, hay manera de cachar para retornar falso es vez de que se muera el sistema? :( Gracias.

Comment: Realmente php ha hecho una implentacion poco extricta con esto, ya que trunca o rellena IV para ajustarse al numero de byte esperados, en lugar de retornar un false, nos retorna un WARNING junto con el resultado. Esto implica tener que hacer una comprobacion mas por parte del programador para verificar que el IV tiene la longitud adecuada, te edito la respuesta.

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta se añadio este if `if(strlen($iv) != openssl_cipher_iv_length('blowfish')) {
        return false;
    }`

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta Tambien añadi un if despues del explode, para garantizar que se extraen los 2 valores, ya que `base64_decode()` puede retornar false si la cadena base64 no es valida, dando lugar a que `$dataIv[1]` no existiera y provocar un `E_NOTICE`. Con estas 2 modificaciones quedaria solventado por el momento.

Comment: Mola de maravilla, yo había intentado cachar todo el asunto este con un código un poco más complejo, pero la verdad es que como no entiendo el correcto funcionamiento de la función me seguía marcando error, muchas gracias @Xerif <3